# Wordpress shows error related to allow_url_fopen

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development, urls, errors

I just installed wordpress with plugins, everything works find except on a 'contact me' page, where I can see an error like this.

> Warning: getimagesize(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in
>   /var/www/foobar.com/wp-content/themes/foobar/backend/theme-components/cs-header/cs_functions.php
>   on line 751
>
> Warning:
>   getimagesize(http://dev.foobar/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/subheader-image-jobline-1.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known in
>   /var/www/foobar.com/wp-content/themes/foobar/backend/theme-components/cs-header/cs_functions.php
>   on line 751

`cs_functions.php` on line 751 is:

```
    if (is_file($cs_upload_dir . $cs_img_name) || is_file($cs_images_dir . $cs_img_name)) {
        if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
            if ($header_banner_image <> '') {
                $banner_image_height = getimagesize($header_banner_image);
            }
        }
    } else if (isset($cs_upload_subdir_file) && is_file($cs_upload_dir . $cs_upload_subdir_file)) {
        if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
           // THIS IS LINE 751
          $banner_image_height = getimagesize($header_banner_image);
        }
    } else {
        $banner_image_height = '';
    }
```

So, I went to `/etc/php.ini` and checked `allow_url_fopen` and it is set to on

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

What is going on? and how do I fix it

Comment: you should basically never call getimagesize on a url.  this will slow down your page tremendously.

Comment: call it on the file path not the url.  url starts with http, path starts with ABSPATH constant (in WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming WP is installed locally, did you make sure to edit your hosts file. Example:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.foobar
```

Comment: Yes. I am sure I have that in my hosts file. Otherwise, I wouldn't even have seen the frontpage of my WP site